# sum 2 columns based on different criteria in the same table

Tags: sql-server

I am on SQL Server 2012 and have a table that looks similar to below:

Table `Trans`:

```
Amount   Itype     hPlant     PostDate
22.45     2         dplf      01/01/2016
45.55     2         dplf      01/01/2016
965.32    4         dplf      02/01/2016
14.25     3         dplf      01/01/2016
72.36     3         esch      01/01/2016
114147.77 2         dplf      01/01/2016
9641.25   4         dplf      01/01/2016
300.00    2         dplf      02/01/2016
```

I need to select the sum of amount with an `itype=2` and `date=01/01/2016` and the sum of amount with `itype=3` and `date=01/01/2016` and `plant=dplf` plus some other data from various other tables.

How do I select the sums on 2 different criteria from one table. I have something similar to this:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(tr.amount), SUM(tr2.amount),
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, tr.date, 1) + ' ' + 'TB  Upload' Reference,
    p.scode 
FROM 
    trans tr 
INNER JOIN 
    plant p on p.hmy = tr.hplant
INNER JOIN  
    trans tr2 on tr2.hplant = tr.hplant 
WHERE 
    tr.date = '01/01/2016' 
    AND tr.itype = 2 
    AND tr2.itype = 3 
    AND tr2.date = '01/01/2016'
GROUP BY  
    tr.date, p.scode
```

My results are not the same as if I ran them individually. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are querying the same table just `sum()` based on different condition. So you don't need to do a self-join to the same table. Use `CASE WHEN . .` to differentiate the condition and `SUM()` it.

```
select sum(case when tr.itype = 2 then tr.amount else 0 end) as amount2,
       sum(case when tr.itype = 3 then tr.amount else 0 end) as amount3,
       convert(varchar(10), tr.date, 1) + ' ' + 'TB  Upload' Reference,
       p.scode 
from   trans tr 
       inner join plant p   on p.hmy = tr.hplant
where  tr.date = '20160101' 
and    tr.itype in ( 2 , 3 )
group by tr.date, p.scode
```

also, always specify a size to the varchar(), or it might back-fire one day.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need some `or`s in the query:

```
SELECT SUM(tr.amount), SUM(tr2.amount),
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), tr.date, 1)+' ' +'TB  Upload' AS Reference, p.scode
FROM trans tr INNER JOIN
     plant p
     on p.hmy = tr.hplant INNER JOIN 
     trans tr2
     ON tr2.hplant = tr.hplant
WHERE (tr.date = '2016-01-01' AND tr.itype = 2) OR
      (tr2.itype = 3 AND tr2.date = '2016-01-01')
GROUP BY tr.date, p.scode;
```

Some notes:

- You need `or` in the `where` clause.  The conditions would have filtered out all rows.
- Use ISO standard formats for dates, such as YYYY-MM-DD
- In SQL Server, never use `varchar()` without a length.  Although it works in your case, the default length varies by context and may not be sufficient.
- Use `as` for column aliases

Comment: According to BOL (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/ms187819.aspx), "To use the ISO 8601 format, you must specify each element in the format. This also includes the T, the colons (:), and the period (.) that are shown in the format" That is YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS. Specifying YYYY-MM-DD may failed in other language. Example : 'SET LANGUAGE French; 
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2015-12-31T00:00:00');
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2015-12-31')';